# How to send a zip file to a github PR as an attachment

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request, github-api-v3

I have a requirement to send a zip file to a open PR as a comment for the PR reviewer. I tried below curl command but getting

`curl -v  -X POST \ -H "Authorization: Bearer <Token>" \ -H "Content-Type: application/zip" \ --data-binary "@zip.zip" \ "https://github.xyz.com/api/v3/repos/{username}/{repository}/issues/2/comments"`

Getting below error

`{ "message": "Problems parsing JSON", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise-server@3.3/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue-comment" }`

Verified JSON content inside zip file, it is proper.

Any suggestions or any sample reference to achieve this. Thank you.